Export Excel table to PowerPoint
I am editing a macro to export the selected table into a PowerPoint slide. However, I am struggling with the code (it makes my laptop app crash) and I was wondering if anyone had a better way of proceeding.
My goal is to automate creating a formatted table in PowerPoint populated with from Excel table data. The table in PowerPoint would be sized the same as the Excel table which can be either selected or named "table_to_export"
After Michael comments, I have added some debug code, but it still crashes my application and I cannot identify eternal loops that could be the reason.
Any clues?
Sub ExportToPowerPoint()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptShape As Object
    Dim SelectedRange As Range
    
    ' Start error handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Set the range of the Excel table based on current selection
    Set SelectedRange = Selection
    
    ' Check if there is a valid selection
    If SelectedRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range in Excel before running the macro."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print "Selected range is valid."
    
    ' Create a new PowerPoint application or get the existing one
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If pptApp Is Nothing Then
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Debug.Print "PowerPoint application set."
    
    ' Make PowerPoint visible
    pptApp.Visible = True
    Debug.Print "PowerPoint made visible."
    
    ' Open an existing presentation or create a new one
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
    If pptPres Is Nothing Then
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Debug.Print "PowerPoint presentation set."
    
    ' Add a new slide
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, 1) ' 1 corresponds to ppLayoutTitle
    Debug.Print "New slide added."
    
    ' Copy the Excel range
    SelectedRange.Copy
    Debug.Print "Excel range copied."
    
    ' Paste the range into PowerPoint
    pptSlide.Shapes.Paste
    Debug.Print "Range pasted into PowerPoint."
    
    ' Get the pasted shape
    Set pptShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
    Debug.Print "Pasted shape set."
    
    ' Adjust the size and position of the pasted object
    pptShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse ' Allow independent resizing of width and height
    pptShape.Left = 50 ' Adjust the left position as needed
    pptShape.Top = 100 ' Adjust the top position as needed
    pptShape.Width = pptPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 100 ' Adjust the width as needed
    pptShape.Height = pptPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 150 ' Adjust the height as needed
    Debug.Print "Pasted shape resized and repositioned."
    
    ' Optionally, you can add a title to the slide
    pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Your Slide Title"
    Debug.Print "Slide title set."
    
    ' Clean up
    Set pptShape = Nothing
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Cleanup done."
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
    
    ' Clean up in case of an error
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not pptShape Is Nothing Then Set pptShape = Nothing
    If Not pptSlide Is Nothing Then Set pptSlide = Nothing
    If Not pptPres Is Nothing Then Set pptPres = Nothing
    If Not pptApp Is Nothing Then
        pptApp.Quit
        Set pptApp = Nothing
    End If
    Debug.Print "Error handling and cleanup done."
End Sub


Consider putting some logging above all "GoTo 0" commands. I assume the application is crashing due to an infinite loop. I assume a screenshot of the excel sheet and link to the excel sheet for easy access is not what you are looking for. And I assume paste special as shown here is not what you are looking for? https://youtu.be/VIQIGs02veA?si=nJXOtNrFl2Vcn1H7&t=91

Hey Michael. Thanks for the tip, I'll try it. The infinite loop might be the reason why it crashes down.
And your right, pasting is not what I am looking for.
Do you have any other idea of how I could proceed ?
Best,
